# .NET Core 3 Web API Multiple Routes detected build error

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have two main controllers (there's a third, auth, but that's not causing the routing error). One is to manipulate at the parent level, the other api controller to manipulate the child level. I won't paste in all the controller code as it's not necessary, just the routes.

There parent level has 3 basic routes. One to get a list of objects, one to get a single object, one to create a new record:

```
[Route("api/npos")]
[ApiController]

// GET NPO LIST
[HttpGet()]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNPOs([FromQuery] PagingParams paging) // code

// GET NPO BY ID
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNPOById(int id) // code

[Route("CreateNPO")]
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNPO([FromBody] NPOtoCreateDto createDto) // code here
```

The child route is to manipulate the user lists in the npos and has a few routes itself.

```
[Route("api/npos/{npoId}/users")]
[ApiController]

// GET USER LIST FOR NPO
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersForNPO(int npoId) // code

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserToNPO(int npoId, string userId) // code

[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUserFromNPO(int npoId, string userId) // code
```

When I run the project via IIS Express, the `UseEndpoints` method in Startup CS throws:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The route parameter name 'npoId' appears more than one time in the route template. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')'
```

Any help? I thought my route config was fairly solid.

Comment: Hi there! Sorry. I haven't had a chance to test it, but I will.

Comment: Hi @J.G.Sable,do you have any updated?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo:

Controller:

```
[Route("api/npos")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET NPO LIST
    [HttpGet()]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetNPOs([FromQuery] PagingParams paging) // code

    // GET NPO BY ID
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetNPOById(int id) // code

    [Route("CreateNPO")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNPO([FromBody] NPOtoCreateDto createDto) // code here
}


[Route("api/npos/{npoId}/users")]
[ApiController]
public class ChildController: ControllerBase
{
    // GET USER LIST FOR NPO
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersForNPO(int npoId) // code

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserToNPO(int npoId, string userId) // code

    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUserFromNPO(int npoId, string userId) // code
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();          
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

BTW,if the two controller contains inheritance relationship like below:

```
[Route("api/npos")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{}

[Route("api/npos/{npoId}/users")]
[ApiController]
public class ChildController: ValuesController
{}
```

You need to change `GetUsersForNPO` route,because when ChildController extends the ValuesController,ChildController owns the actions which ValuesController have.`GetNPOs` and `GetUsersForNPO` action will conflict.Although the parameter is bind from different source.`GetNPOs` get parameter from query and `GetUsersForNPO` get from route,but no matter route and query,they are all optional.So this makes request match multiple endpoints.As a workaround,just change the `GetUsersForNPO` route like below:

```
[Route("GetUsersForNPO")]
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersForNPO(int npoId)
```